# Convert a string representation of dictionaries to actual dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a very large json file that I opened and stored in a variable called `data`. A snippet of printing `data` gives me this output of type string:

```
'{"_index": "11_20190714_184325_01", "_type": "11", "_id": "1feb78aff16852ed", "_score": 0.0, "fields": {"c_u": ["hvhprecision.com"], "tawgs.id": ["p10813", "p449", "p6426", "p6427"]}}{"_index": "11_20190714_184325_01", "_type": "11", "_id": "786fd4ad2415aa7b", "_score": 0.0, "fields": {"c_u": ["thomsonreuters.com"], "tawgs.id": ["p12519", "p510", "p6426"]}}{"_index": "11_20190714_184325_01", "_type": "11", "_id": "5826e7cbd92d951a", "_score": 0.0, "fields": {"tawgs.id": ["p12505", "p18053", "p6426", "p816", "p826", "p8453", "p8458"]}}'
```

I need to convert this string representation of a dictionary to an actual dictionary in order to flatten it and create a dataframe.

However, when I try:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(data)
```

I get an **"Invalid Syntax"** error.

Trying this code:

```
with open("es-output.json", "r") as f
    dictionary =  json.loads(f.read())
```

gives me this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 184 (char 183)
```

Doing a simple:

```
json.loads(data)
```

also outputs the same error as above: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 184 (char 183)`.

I have no idea why it's not working to convert a string to a dictionary, especially with the **ast** library.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: This is invalid JSON/Python: it contains a `}}{`, without a comma (`,`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string

```
data = '{"_index": "11_20190714_184325_01", "_type": "11", "_id": "1feb78aff16852ed", "_score": 0.0, "fields": {"c_u": ["hvhprecision.com"], "tawgs.id": ["p10813", "p449", "p6426", "p6427"]}}{"_index": "11_20190714_184325_01", "_type": "11", "_id": "786fd4ad2415aa7b", "_score": 0.0, "fields": {"c_u": ["thomsonreuters.com"], "tawgs.id": ["p12519", "p510", "p6426"]}}{"_index": "11_20190714_184325_01", "_type": "11", "_id": "5826e7cbd92d951a", "_score": 0.0, "fields": {"tawgs.id": ["p12505", "p18053", "p6426", "p816", "p826", "p8453", "p8458"]}}'
```

contains three separate JSON objects. You can't create one dictionary from the three of them.

You will need to separate them first, then run them through `ast`. You can do that by using `replace`:

```
data = data.replace("}{", "},{")
ast.literal_eval(data)
```

This returns a tuple with your various dictionaries:

```
({'_index': '11_20190714_184325_01', '_type': '11', '_id': '1feb78aff16852ed', '_score': 0.0, 'fields': {'c_u': ['hvhprecision.com'], 'tawgs.id': ['p10813', 'p449', 'p6426', 'p6427']}}, {'_index': '11_20190714_184325_01', '_type': '11', '_id': '786fd4ad2415aa7b', '_score': 0.0, 'fields': {'c_u': ['thomsonreuters.com'], 'tawgs.id': ['p12519', 'p510', 'p6426']}}, {'_index': '11_20190714_184325_01', '_type': '11', '_id': '5826e7cbd92d951a', '_score': 0.0, 'fields': {'tawgs.id': ['p12505', 'p18053', 'p6426', 'p816', 'p826', 'p8453', 'p8458']}})
```

Comment: I thought instead of 3 dictionaries it was just multiple json objects, which should be convertible to a dictionary?

Comment: Even if that is the case is there any work around I would be able to do to just take the string and correctly normalize it and convert it to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: ahh got it, not sure if you would be willing to supplement, but one more question would be how would I convert that tuple to a correctly flattened dataframe? when I do pd.DataFrame(data) it doesn't parse the tuple correctly. I'm also semi-unfamiliar with how tuples work for converting to dataframes.

Comment: @aesthetics I would recommend opening new questions for issues like this as it is getting further and further away from the original question. Here is an example: do `ans = ast.literal_eval(data)`, then `pd.DataFrame(ans[0])` creates a DataFrame. You need to do it for each dictionary.